# vtkAngleRepresentation2D calculation bug?

Tags: vtk

I use vtkAngleRepresentation2D (with vtkAngleWidget) from VTK 5.X. It seems like this class provides different values for the same angle. The representation draws the current angle value on the vtk window (e.g. 103.205), but the method getAngle() provides a minimal different value (e.g. 103.408)?

Does anybody know why or how to avoid this behavior? I want both interfaces to provide the absolute same value.

Regards,
Michael